# CFspreadsheet adding a % to format a column

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I am using CF10 and trying to add a % sign to a spreadsheet.

I am having an issue with adding a % sign on my 5th column entries. (Only the entries starting the second row (not the header) and not the blank cells when the query is done running.

```
<cftry>

    <cfset objSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetNew()>
    <cfset assocRows = ''>

    <!--- Create and format the header row. --->
    <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, "Associate Name,Location,Checklists Generated by Associate,Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s),Associate Percentage of Location Total" )>

    <cfset rowNumber = 1 />
    <cfoutput query="GetEmployeeInfo">
        <cfset rowNumber++ />
        <cfset rowList = "'#(rnA eq 1)?assoc_name:''#','#(rnl eq 1)?trans_location:''#','#checklistsByAssocLoc#','#assocChecklistsByLoc#','#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct)#'">
        <!--- Make list of rows --->
        <cfif (rnA eq 1)>
          <cfset assocRows = ListAppend(assocRows, rowNumber)>
        </cfif>
        <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, rowList)>
        <cfif rnTotAssoc EQ 1>
            <cfset rowNumber++ />
            <cfset rowList = "'Associate Total','','#totalChecklistsByAssoc#','#totalAssocChecklistsByAllFilteredLoc#','#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)#'" >
            <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow( objSpreadsheet, rowList )>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfset SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(objSpreadsheet,1,25)> 
    <cfset SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(objSpreadsheet,2,25)>
    <cfset SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(objSpreadsheet,3,25)>
    <cfset SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(objSpreadsheet,4,25)>
    <cfset SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(objSpreadsheet,5,25)>
    <!--- Move the line here --->
    <cfset SpreadsheetFormatRow( objSpreadsheet, {bold=true, textwrap="true", alignment="center"}, 1 )>
    <cfloop list="#assocRows#" index="i">
      <cfset SpreadsheetFormatCell(objSpreadsheet, {'bold' : 'true'}, i, 1)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=CS_#Dateformat(NOW(),'MMDDYYYY')#.xls"> 
    <cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#SpreadsheetReadBinary( objSpreadsheet )#">

    <cfcatch type = "any">
        #rowList#
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I have tried adding:
`'#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %'"`
which then excel doesnt know the correct format.

Then I tried:
`<cfset spreadsheetFormatCell( objSpreadsheet, {dataformat: "0.00%"}, 2 )>`

Which then just through an error:

> Parameter validation error for the SPREADSHEETFORMATCELL function.

Any help on how to add this % sign to the 5 column (not the header or blank cells once the query stops) would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Also tried:

`<cfset rowList = "'#(rnA eq 1)?assoc_name:''#','#(rnl eq 1)?trans_location:''#','#checklistsByAssocLoc#','#assocChecklistsByLoc#','#NumberFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct, '0.00')# %'">`

Excel still through the error saying its formatted as text.

Comment: First thing that pops into my mind is `#numberformat(number, mask)# '%'`.

Comment: @DanBracuk am i missing something in my edit? Im still receiving the format issue in excel

Comment: So the sheet gets populated but excel thinks it's text?  It is text.  By the way, your number format mask might give unexpected results for values like 11.34.

Comment: It gets a little green thing in the top left corner of the cell and when you click the cell it pops up an exclamation point saying `the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe.`

Comment: Maybe we have different requirements because I would simply accept that.  When I export data to excel it's with the expectation that the user is going to edit it somehow.  That being the case, I don't concern myself too much with formatting.  If the user doesn't like it, they can change it.

Comment: lol I wish it was that easy for me. If I remove the % and just drop it in. Excel accepts everything correctly. I am just trying to figure out how to make it perfect

Comment: What is the column number for the value you are trying to show in `"0.00%"` format?

Comment: the column number is 5

Comment: `'#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct)#'"` and `'#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)#'"` are in that column besides the header

Comment: Try `<cfset spreadsheetFormatColumn( objSpreadsheet, {dataformat: "0.00%"}, 5 )>` after loops are done.

Comment: it added the % but now the decimal part was wrong and it only added the percent sign for the first 33 out of 73 lines

Comment: is it possible to run through column 5 and do an ignore errors?